# JVM metrics and Service Name Issues with opentelemetry

Tags: java, prometheus, open-telemetry, otlp-grpc, otel

I am using opentelemetry to send metrics to prometheus and I am using **otlp** exporter. But I am facing 2 issues there.

1. Service name is coming as unknown_serive:java .
2. jvm/auto-instrumented metrics are not coming.

If anyone can help here, it would be great. Thanks!

For fixing the service-name issue, I tried 3 solutions,

1. I set **OTEL_SERVICE_NAME** variable in config map.
2. I tried passing **-Dotel.service.name** but this is also not working.
3. I tried passing **service.name** value in **OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES**, but that too doesn't work.

For jvm metrics, i set **-Dotel.javaagent.enabled=true**, but metrics still not coming.

My **otel-config.yaml** file is

```
exporters:
    otlp:
        endpoint: some-endpoint
        tls:
            insecure: true
    prometheusremotewrite:
        endpoint: some-endpoint
        resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
            enabled: true
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using the otel java agent, but also maybe adding your own custom instrumentation. How are you configuring the SDK? You should use the env vars / system properties [documented here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure). Minimally, you'll want to configure `OTEL_SERVICE_NAME` and set `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT` to collector's OTLP endpoint. You'll also want to ensure that your custom instrumentation uses the same `OpenTelemetry` instance as the otel agent by calling `GlobalOpenTelemetry.get()`.